# Symfony Array Collection as Entity Property

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to associate an ArrayCollection to a database column created by an Entity?

For example, I have two entities: Household and Pet Type.

Household current has a property for Pet Type, but it expects the Pet Type object, so only one can chosen at the moment.

I'd like Household to be able to have multiple Pet Types. So instead of having to choose between a Dog or a Cat, they can choose Dog AND Cat.

I have tried doing this, but I get the following error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\Household::setPetType() must be an instance of
>   Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\PetType, instance of
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given

I'm assuming I'd need to change property for petType in the Household entity in order to associate to more than one pet type?

Comment: In your case Entity has Many to Many relation. ( One household can have many PetType and One PetType can be in many household).  Post your entity classes for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I typically post as much code as possible, but there's an NDA in place on this project, so I'm not sure how much info I can divulge. Using your input and the answer below, I was able to get this working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description it seems that `Household` and `PetType` has a cardinality of *m-to-one*; that means that an Household record could have only a `PetType` while a `PetType` could be associated to more than one `Household` record.

From DB point of view that means foreign key into `Household` table. If you want to make possible a "multiple" connection between `Household` and `PetType`, you have to modify your relationship between entities.

Just an example (disclaimer: your entities could be named differently and I didn't test this code. I'm explaining here a concept, not working on runnable code as your example didn't came with snippet examples)

```
class Household 
{
  //some properties

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PetType", inversedBy="households")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="household_pettype")
   */
  $pet_types;

  //some methods

  public function addPetType(PetType $petType)
  {
    $this->pet_types[] = $petType;

    return $this;
  }

  public function setPetTypes(ArrayCollection $petTypes)
  {
    $this->pet_types = $petTypes;

    return $this;
  }

  public function removePetType(PetType $petType)
  {
    $this->pet_types->removeElement($petType);
  }

  public function getPetTypes()
  {
    return $this->pet_types;
  }
}
```

---

```
class PetType
{
  //some properties

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Household", mappedBy="pet_types")
   */
   $households;

  //some methods

  public function addHousehold(Household $household)
  {
    $this->households[] = $household;

    return $this;
  }

  public function setHouseholds(ArrayCollection $households)
  {
    $this->households = $households;

    return $this;
  }

  public function removeHousehold(Household $household)
  {
    $this->households->removeElement($household);
  }

  public function getHousehold()
  {
    return $this->households;
  }
}
```

After that you need to run again

`php app/consolle doctrine:schema:update --force`

This will update your DB schema and, because new cardinality is *m-to-n*, a relationship table named `household_pettype` will be created (that will hold only foreign keys from other two tables)

After that you could alternatively use two methods (from household point of view)

- `->addPetType($petType);` that will append a `PetType` object to
  `Household` collection
- `->setPetTypes($petTypeArrayCollection);` that will set in a shot all
  `PetTypes`

Comment: Thanks! I figured as much. I was 99% sure I'd need a relation table, but just wanted to verify. I've got the solution by implementing a number of elements from your answer.